# Google Spreadsheet Script: setValue

Tags: google-sheets, setvalue

This is my code (it is fully working as intended).

```
function concatenate() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");

  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();

  for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
    var datad = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var datae = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var concatde = sheet.getRange(i, 4).setValue(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
  }
}
```

However my question is regarding the line `var concatde = sheet.getRange(i, 4).setValue(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());` in my code.I wish to add a string at the end of the setValue as well shown in this line.

```
var concatde = sheet.getRange(i, 4).setValue(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(), "A");
```

However, when I run it with the string "A", I get this error message: 
Cannot find method setValue(object,string). (line 12, file "Code")

Any suggestions for me to be able to have a string at the end of it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see `setValue()` only takes in one parameter.

Google Apps Script is just javascript so you can do something like below:

```
var concatde = sheet.getRange(i, 4).setValue(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() + "A");
```

Note the '+' after `getValue()`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure about + as thought it may try to do a mathematical operation like 1+2=3.

Comment: The quotation marks will prevent it from doing math and will instead append. e.g. 1 + "1" = 11 but 1+1 = 2.